# Backbone pushState routes

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, pushstate

I'm trying to deal with backbone.js pushState for change hashtags on pretty urls. Using `localhost` and the path to my script is `http://localhost/test/backbone/test.html`.  But each time the click is throwing me to the `localhost/login`. What am I doing wrong?

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "login": "getPost",
        "*actions": "defaultRoute"
    }
});

var app_router = new AppRouter;

app_router.on('route:getPost', function (id) {
    alert( "login" );   
});

app_router.on('route:defaultRoute', function (actions) {
    alert( actions ); 
});

app_router.navigate("/login", {trigger: true});
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: '/login/'});
```

Comment: which `click` and where ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966321/how-to-properly-use-html5-pushstate-in-backbone-js

Comment: `<a href="/login">login</a>` Maybe I don't understand something? Should I add handler for click (for example return false or prevent.default for links?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need add:

```
$(document).delegate("a", "click", function(evt) {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var protocol = this.protocol + "//";

    if (href.slice(protocol.length) !== protocol && protocol !== 'javascript://' &&      href.substring(0, 1) !== '#') {
        evt.preventDefault();

        Backbone.history.navigate(href, true);
    }
});
```

And last 2 strings should be:

```
app_router.navigate("/login", {trigger: true}); // <- should remove this string
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root:"test/backbone/test.html"});
```